Discord.py, sending a direct message in a server
How do I send a message in a server that only the player that ran the command can see?
@bot.command(description="says hello... yeah")
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"hello {ctx.author.mention}!!!", ephemeral=True)

I tried using an ephemeral, but it doesn't work.

If you tried using an ephemeral, please show us what you tried in code which would be more useful. Also, please format your code properly and use a code block instead of a inline code block.

Does this answer your question? How would I send an ephemeral message in discord.py?

Ephemerals only work with interactions, i.e. slash command responses, buttons/selects, modal responses etc. You're gonna need to use slash commands if you need that feature or you can send the message in DMs.

Slash commands examples and guide: https://about.abstractumbra.dev/dpy

